# Site breaks(doesn't render farther) if php included file fails, can I prevent this somehow?

Tags: php, html, include, rendering

I have php file with html code inside, I have div showing Currency rates from included rates.php file (it gets rates from local National Bank Api), when api has problems (rates.php shows error and doesn't show rates) all the site (code after this php include) breaks, doesn't render, can I somehow prevent it from stopping render?

```
    <?

 $client = new SoapClient('http://nbg.gov.ge/currency.wsdl');
 print ("Exchange Rates: 1 USD - ");
 print $client->GetCurrency('USD').'₾ |';
 $client2 = new SoapClient('http://nbg.gov.ge/currency.wsdl');
 print (" 1 EUR - ");
 print $client2->GetCurrency('EUR').'₾';

?>
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVA5M.png)

Comment: You should add proper error checking to the PHP so that if some data isn't present/a reply isn't received then it will handle that and do something in a controlled way.  Without scripts or the knowing the problems you are encountering it will be difficult to help solve this.

Comment: I added php file code, which gets currency rates from Bank api.

Comment: Can you also include any error messages that you say are displayed?

Comment: Perhaps https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-soap-fault.php may give some ideas how to handle SOAP problems.

Comment: I included link to screenshot, site doesn't allow to attach images yet.

Comment: Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401452/how-to-catch-uncaught-soapfault-exception.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @Makyen I am sorry, I understand, but I received this screenshot from the person who mentioned this issue, I can't see error in "text" now, because now site works fine (but sometimes problem with rates.php (with source of this file) happen and this makes site down).

Comment: now my issue is resolved with help of RiggsFolly, I checked his (her) answer as helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failing to instantiate the Soap Client should throw an Exception so you could try something like this

```
<?php

try {
    $client = new SoapClient('http://nbg.gov.ge/currency.wsdl');

    print ("Exchange Rates: 1 USD - ");
    print $client->GetCurrency('USD').'₾ |';
    print (" 1 EUR - ");
    print $client->GetCurrency('EUR').'₾';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'A nice message telling the user that something is wrong, try again in a little while';
    //echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

> PS You dont need 2 instances of SoapClient, one will do nicely.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works fine :)